# Issue in running sudo commands remotely from a c# application.

Tags: c#, linux, ssh, remote-access

I am writing an utility in c# to get system information of remote machines. In certain Linux machines direct login to root is not allowed and some of the commands i am running require root privileges. I am able to establish SSH session (I am using Renci SSh libraries for same).

Researching leads me to believe in such cases I need to use sudo. But when I am using sudo remotely like this it is not working.

The first part of code works when I am get root access. Where direct root access is not allowed - the first part does not return anything and the second part using sudo is also not returning anything). Please see the code I am using (client is the name assigned to SshClient).

I don't know Linux well enough. Request guidance on how to approach this issue.

```
client.RunCommand("cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep model | grep name");
client.RunCommand("dmidecode -s system-manufacturer");

client.RunCommand("sudo cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep model | grep name");
client.RunCommand("sudo dmidecode -s system-manufacturer");
```

Comment: First try the commands by hand in a terminal that supports ssh (git bash?), then run them from c#. This way, you will actually see what goes wrong. Now you're just painting walls with your eyes closed...

Comment: Thanks Wouter. I did try the commands directly on a couple of those "remote" machines terminals. They work directly on the terminal. But not through c#. I will try using ssh terminals as suggested by you too.

Comment: used putty and connected remotely. Works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what finally worked for me. Posting it for those who come here with similar issues.

1. requiretty should either be commented out in the sudo file or set as not required for the particular user.
2. command structure should be as

   ```
   echo <password> | sudo -S <linux command>"
   ```